# Race condition in partitioning with dynamic table creation

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm trying to implement table partitioning with dynamic table creation using `BEFORE INSERT` trigger to create new tables and indexes when necesarry using following solution:

```
create table mylog (
    mylog_id serial not null primary key,
    ts timestamp(0) not null default now(),
    data text not null
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mylog_insert() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        _name text;
        _from timestamp(0);
        _to timestamp(0);
    BEGIN
        SELECT into _name 'mylog_'||replace(substring(date_trunc('day', new.ts)::text from 0 for 11), '-', '');
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name=_name) then
            SELECT into _from date_trunc('day', new.ts)::timestamp(0);
            SELECT into _to _from + INTERVAL '1 day';
            EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE '||_name||' () INHERITS (mylog)';
            EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE '||_name||' ADD CONSTRAINT ts_check CHECK (ts >= '||quote_literal(_from)||' AND ts < '||quote_literal(_to)||')';
            EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX '||_name||'_ts_idx on '||_name||'(ts)';
        END IF;
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '||_name||' (ts, data) VALUES ($1, $2)' USING
            new.ts, new.data;
        RETURN null;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER mylog_insert
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON mylog
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE mylog_insert();
```

Everything works as expected but each day when concurrent `INSERT` statements are being fired for the first time that day, one of them fails trying to "create table that already exists". I suspect that this is caused by the triggers being fired concurrently and both trying to create new table and only one can succeed.

I could be using `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST` but I cannot detect the outcome so I cannot reliably create constraints and indexes.

What can I do to avoid such problem? Is there any way to signal the fact that the table has been already created to other concurrent triggers? Or maybe there is a way of knowing if `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` created new table or not?

Comment: just don't do it. Trigger should be fast as is possible. If you would to write safe without Race Condition code, then your code will not be fast. So don't do it, if it is possible! The safe solution needs locks on some critical tables, or advisory locks can be used too.

Comment: Locks and advisory locks won’t work because the table will be visible only after trigger completes and yet create table will still fail. But exceptions will. Look at my answer below. I agree that this is a performance disaster though.

Comment: You have to ensure so in one time only one process will start create table, and it can be done by transaction advisory lock. The visibility of table is not important because advisory lock is released on transaction end, and in this same moment the new table will be visible.

Comment: I did try this with advisory lock and it does not work because after advisory lock is released, table created in another transaction (still in progress) is invisible in information schema but create table will fail.

Comment: You have to use transactional advisory locks.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is create a pgAgent job to run every day and create 3 months of tables ahead of time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION avl_db.create_alltables()
  RETURNS numeric AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rec record;
BEGIN

    FOR rec IN     
        SELECT    date_trunc('day', i::timestamp without time zone) as table_day
        FROM      generate_series(now()::date, 
                                  now()::date + '3 MONTH'::interval, 
                                  '1 DAY'::interval) as i
    LOOP 
        PERFORM avl_db.create_table (rec.table_day);
    END LOOP; 

    PERFORM avl_db.avl_partition(now()::date, 
                                 now()::date + '3 MONTH'::interval);
    RETURN 0;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION avl_db.create_alltables()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

- create_table is very similar to your `CREATE TABLE` code
- avl_partition update the `BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER` but I saw you do that part with dynamic query. Will have to check again that.

Also I see you are doing inherit, but you are missing a very important `CONSTRAINT`

```
CONSTRAINT route_sources_20170601_event_time_check CHECK (
      event_time >= '2017-06-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone 
  AND event_time <  '2017-06-02 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone
)
```

This improve the query a lot when doing a search for `event_time` because doesn't have to check every table.

See how doesn't check all tables for the month:

[image]

Comment: There is the time constraint `ts_check`. It is also being created dynamically. But it is an interesting approach to create the tables upfront.

Comment: I schedule the job to run every day. so really only create one day 3 months in the future because all other days are already create. In retrospective I was paranoid about the job fail to run.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I wrapped `CREATE TABLE` in `BEGIN...EXCEPTION` block that catches `duplicate_table` exception - this did the trick, but creating the tables upfront in a cronjob is much better approach performance-wise.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mylog_insert() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        _name text;
        _from timestamp(0);
        _to timestamp(0);
    BEGIN
        SELECT into _name 'mylog_'||replace(substring(date_trunc('day', new.ts)::text from 0 for 11), '-', '');
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name=_name) then
            SELECT into _from date_trunc('day', new.ts)::timestamp(0);
            SELECT into _to _from + INTERVAL '1 day';
            BEGIN
                EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE '||_name||' () INHERITS (mylog)';
                EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE '||_name||' ADD CONSTRAINT ts_check CHECK (ts >= '||quote_literal(_from)||' AND ts < '||quote_literal(_to)||')';
                EXECUTE 'CREATE INDEX '||_name||'_ts_idx on '||_name||'(ts)';
            EXCEPTION WHEN duplicate_table THEN
                RAISE NOTICE 'table exists -- ignoring';
            END;
    END IF;
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '||_name||' (ts, data) VALUES ($1, $2)' USING
            new.ts, new.data;
        RETURN null;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```